# How does comparator functions work behind the scene?

Tags: c++, comparator

Why does this code gives runtime error :

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std:length_error'
> what(): basic_string::_M_create.

while changing the condition in comp function to `s1.size()  < s2.size()` gives correct answer.

```cpp
static bool comp(const string& s1,const string& s2){
    return s1.size()<=s2.size();
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<string> words(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        cin>>words[i];
    }
    sort(words.begin(),words.end(),comp);
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        cout<<words[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compare parameter for sort must satisfy the [*Compare* named requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) In your case it doesn't, so you get undefined behavour. The likely cause for your exact error is probably the iterator going past the end operator, since it relies e.g. on the fact that the `comp` relation is antireflexive

Comment: Change `s1.size()<=s2.size()` to `s1.size()<s2.size()` to make your code valid.  The sort comparator must return true **only** if the first parameter **must** be ordered before the second.  You have written a comparator that will claim `"AB"` must be ordered before `"CD"` and `"CD"` must be ordered before `"AB"`.  And that's impossible to satisfy.